# "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017" C# class diagrams

Tags: c#

I just created a  new project / Class Library (.Net Framework) and I try to see the class diagrams, to get this I right click the solution explorer and it is supposed that an option to see the class diagram should be displayed but I don’t see it.

Comment: Are you sure community edition of VS offers this?

Comment: Please, read [how to ask useful questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a part of visual studio by default any more. You need to install it as an extension. If you type "Class Designer" into the quick launch bar in the top right corner (or `Ctrl+Q` keyboard shortcut) it should give you the option to install it.

After it installs and you reopen visual studio the option should become available. I have just tested this in VS2017 community and confirmed it worked on a .NET Framework project (not on .net core/standard)

Comment: Dear Kirlac,

I really appreciate your quick help, I installed the Class Designer following your steps and now I have that option available in my Visual Studio.
Thank you so much and congratulations !

Comment: Dear Kirlac,

I really appreciate your quick help, I installed the Class Designer following your steps and now I have that option available in my Visual Studio.
Thank you so much and congratulations !